# How to know in w2ui grid which cell was clicked?

Tags: javascript, w2ui

The w2ui grid does not have an event to know which cell the user clicked, so to know which record an which field in the record was clicked.
http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/grid/events
Is there a way to know it?

For example here it detects the record, but not the exact cell clicked (for example the email) as there is no event for this:

```
$('#grid').w2grid({
    name    : 'grid',
    columns: [
        { field: 'recid', text: 'ID', size: '50px' },
        { field: 'lname', text: 'Last Name', size: '30%' },
        { field: 'fname', text: 'First Name', size: '30%' },
        { field: 'email', text: 'Email', size: '40%' },
        { field: 'sdate', text: 'End Date', size: '120px' }
    ],
    records: [
        { recid: 1, fname: 'John', lname: 'doe', email: 'vitali@gmail.com', sdate: '1/3/2012' },
        { recid: 2, fname: 'Stuart', lname: 'Motzart', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '2/4/2012' },
        { recid: 3, fname: 'Jin', lname: 'Franson', email: '--', sdate: '4/23/2012' },
        { recid: 4, fname: 'Susan', lname: 'Ottie', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '5/3/2012' },
        { recid: 5, fname: 'Kelly', lname: 'Silver', email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', sdate: '4/3/2012' },
        { recid: 6, fname: 'Francis', lname: 'Gatos', email: 'vitali@gmail.com', sdate: '2/5/2012' }
    ],
    onClick: function(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: please include a sample of your code (the w2ui grid) html and javascript in your question. Also show what you tried to make this work and where you got stuck. Then I'm sure someone will have an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

With "click" event in w2ui you can get event object and for doing a change on the cell you can use this code:

```
w2ui.grid.on('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
    event.target.style.display="none";
});
```

You can see the document from this [link.](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2grid.onClick)

Comment: I just saw that the event object has a "column" property (also the recid) with the number of column clicked. Is curious that nobody tells this, which of course is the answer.